# NotAMockException When Trying to Test Delete Requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, testing, mocking

I'm trying to test my delete requests in a `rest API`. When I execute i get the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
```

This is my code for the test:

```
    @Test
public void testDeleteModules_OK() throws Exception{
    doNothing().when(modRepo).deleteById(10);
    mockMvc.perform(delete("/Modules/10")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    verify(modRepo, times(1)).deleteById(1);
}
```

Comment: How is `modRepo` defined?

Comment: @Autowired
 private ModulesRepository modRepo;

Comment: Have you tried using `@MockBean` instead of `@Autowired`? Maybe this could be helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean

Comment: Thanks, now instead I get the error java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
This is the call for delete request in my controller  `@DeleteMapping("/Modules/{id}")
 void deleteModules(@PathVariable int id) {
  modRepo.deleteById(id);
 }`

Comment: That would be another question.  But we may still need more information about if there were any `@RequestMapping` type methods on the `class` containing this mapping, and how you're creating the `MockMVC` instance.